# Kaha DB message store to persist Files in camel

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint

This is my Camel Route:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:///c:/"/>
  <to uri="file:///D:/"/>
</route>
```

In case of any failure in this route I want to persistently store files in Kaha DB so that files won't be lost. But am not aware of `blueprint.xml` configuration of Kaha DB persistence for storing files. And my `Activemq.xml` file is as follows

```
<broker brokerName="kahaDB_Persistence" persistent="true" useShutdownHook="false">
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${data}/kahadb/"
                journalMaxFileLength="100mb"
                concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues="false"
                concurrentStoreAndDispatchTopics="false"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
</broker>
```

Please advise me how to connect to this KahaDB from `blueprint.xml` by considering above mentioned route.

Answer (score 0):

Camel's file component has a built in archive feature that saves files that have been processed. It copies them into a folder called ".camel", but it can be changed with a configuration option.

I would not recommend using KahaDB, as it doesn't fit the "right tool for the job" mantra.

[Camel File component docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: Maat thanks for respose, i don't want files to be .camel or any other directory. These will be gone once ESB is down. Tried noop=true as well but once ESB is re-started it process old file as well. My scenario is exactly like message persistence once message is delivered to consumer then it will be deleted from the Database.

Comment: I don't know what you mean regarding the files going away after restart. We use a .done and a .failed folder for file archival. It works. As to the noop=true and reprocessing of old files upon restart, you would need to investigate the idempotent settings / options to avoid that, but keeping the files in the incoming folder is probably not the correct solution at any rate.

Comment: +1 Steve. The behavior described by user1468077 is inconsistent with default Camel file component and inconsistent with using KahaDB by itself.